# Нужен комментарий по работе ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

Изучаю сейчас использование Google Play Billing и в статье написано:

> Вам следует запутать свой открытый ключ Google Play и код Billing Google Play, чтобы злоумышленнику было сложно перепроектировать протоколы безопасности и другие компоненты приложения. Как минимум, мы рекомендуем запустить в своем коде инструмент запутывания, такой как Proguard. Чтобы запутать ваш код с помощью Proguard, вы должны добавить следующую строку в ваш файл конфигурации Proguard:
>   -keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

Но, когда я осваивал ProGuard, то команда -keep вроде бы как защищает код от  обфускации и я даже пробовал это сделать наглядно для себя.

Вопрос. В чем же тогда заключается запутывание о котором говорит Гугл?

Comment: Не могу сказать конкретно про биллинг, но у библиотек может быть внешний API - это классы и методы, которые вызываются из других приложений и системы. Если такие классы и методы будут переименованы обфускатором, то их работа сломается. То есть гугл предлагает вам запутать ваш код, а не код библиотеки и чтобы вы не нарвались на непонятки указано что надо добавить строку, защищающую API их библиотеки.

Comment: @woesss, хм...Вы правы... так оно наверное и есть. Об этом я не подумал. Спасибо.